# How to create SparkSession in Quarkus App?

Tags: java, apache-spark, quarkus

I'm trying to create simple Quarkus application with Apache Spark, to then later deploy it on kubernetes cluster. Application is starting with no errors (quarkus dev mode) but for some reason it can't create SparkSession (also no errors here, app just hangs when I invoke rest endpoint that uses SparkSession).

In below code, when I write "return sparkSessionBean.toString();" in ExampleResource "hello" method, it runs correctly, but when I try to "return sparkSessionBean.getSpark().toString();" the request hangs forever, no errors.

When I run the same code in standalone application with main method (without Quarkus), it runs correctly (creates SparkSession and executes some job).

I've tested this on Quarkus 3.5.3 and 3.8.1 + Spark 3.5.0 + Java 17.

Is there any problem with using Spark with Quarkus?

Resource:

```
package com.example;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    @Inject
    SparkSessionBean sparkSessionBean;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return sparkSessionBean.getSpark().toString();
    }
}
```

SparkSessionBean:

```
package com.example;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SparkSessionBean {
    private static final String WAREHOUSE_PATH = "s3a://iceberg";
    private SparkSession spark;

    public SparkSession getSpark() {
        if (spark == null) {
            spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .appName("Java Spark Iceberg Example")
                    .master("local")
                    .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")

                    //Filesystem (MinIO) config
                    .config("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
                    .config("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000")
                    .config("fs.s3a.access.key", "key123")
                    .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret123")
                    .config("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", WAREHOUSE_PATH)

                    //Nessie catalog config
                    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.13:1.3.0,org.projectnessie.nessie-integrations:nessie-spark-extensions-3.5_2.13:0.77.1")
                    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions,org.projectnessie.spark.extensions.NessieSparkSessionExtensions")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieCatalog")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie.authentication.type", "NONE")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie.uri", "http://localhost:19120/api/v1")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie.ref", "main")
                    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "nessie")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.nessie.warehouse", WAREHOUSE_PATH)
                    .getOrCreate();
        }
        return spark;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.8.1</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <spark.version>3.5.0</spark.version>
        <iceberg.version>1.4.3</iceberg.version>
        <hadoop.version>3.3.4</hadoop.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- QUARKUS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPARK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ICEBERG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
            <artifactId>iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${iceberg.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HADOOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OTHER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                    <goal>generate-code</goal>
                    <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                </native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>native</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>native</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
    </properties>
</profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```